# Add or request a user to add email id to contact list. Is this possible automatically using javamail ?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have written a java program to send email via SMTP. I would like to know how I can request the user to add my email Id to his address-book/Contact list in his client automatically/manually. Is there a way for me to do it from within my java code. I would like this feature as my emails will not get listed as spam/junk. I am using javamail API.

Thank you,
Nagarajan

Comment: Javamail will not help you on this, you could maintain a local address book if you want

Answer (score 0):

NOT POSSIBLE!! You can't do that ,Email will be just mail.Listing your emailid and other things(spam,junk mail) to be done by receiver only.Who receive they have to configure.

Comment: Thank you sunleo, I am aware of it but wanted to know if there is a  possibility.